# Shifting first indexes

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array size of 3, and I am trying to shift the first index to the last place, while shifting the others to the left.  for example:

{1,2,3} to {2,3,1}

here is my code

```
 int[] nums = {1,2,3}; 
 int[] numsShifted = new int[3];

 for(int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++)
 {
  int tempNum = nums[i];
  numsRotated[i] = nums[i + 1];
  numsRotated[i+1] = tempNum;
 }
```

The issue I am having is the last index of the array, i get the incorrect value.  Thanks.

Comment: Of course you get the wrong result; you aren't storing `nums[0]` anywhere...

Comment: Yea I realized that right after I posted it, tried to close the post but my level isnt high enough, thanks anyways.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Actually, he's not really overwriting the original array...

Answer (score 2):

Just do a simple shift and then copy the first number on the last position:

```
 int[] nums = {1,2,3}; 
 int[] numsShifted = new int[3];

 int temp = nums[0];
 for(int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++)
 {
    numsShifted[i - 1] = nums[i];
 }
 numsShifted[nums.length - 1] = temp;
```

**Edit**: You don't actually need to safe the first item, since you are not overwriting the original array.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to store the first element outside the loop and then begin shifting. After the end of the loop simply put the first element stored as the last element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

you have to save the nums[0] value;

```
int saved = nums[0];

for(int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
  numsShifted[i] = nums[i+1];
}
numsShifted[numsShifted.length - 1] = saved;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] nums = {1,2,3}; 
int[] numsShifted = new int[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++)
    {
        int tempNum = nums[i]; //tempNum=1, tempNum=2
        numsRotated[i] = nums[i + 1]; //numsRotated[0]=2, numsRotated[1]=3
        numsRotated[i+1] = tempNum; //numsRotated[1]=1, numsRotated[2]=2  <- this is incorrect and the loop ends
    }
```

at the end, you have 2,3,2. You will need to fix your loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the code you wrote, just fix it as I did.
Otherwise, the other answers are quite good!

```
    int[] nums = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] numsShifted = new int[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) { //Do one more iteration
        if (i + 1 > 2) { //If this is the last element, we take the first one of nums
            numsShifted[i] = nums[0];
        } else { //Otherwise we do as you did in your code
            numsShifted[i] = nums[i + 1];
            numsShifted[i + 1] = nums[i];
        }            
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numsShifted));
```

EDIT :
Remove tempNum as you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};
int[] b = new int[3];

for(int j = 0 , i = 2 ; j < a.length ; j++)
{
     b[i++] = a[j];
     if(i >= 3)
     i = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other options, without loops:

```
public static int[] queueFirst(int[] in) {
   int len = in.length;   
   if (len <= 1) return in;
   int[] ret  = Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.copyOfRange(in, 1, len), len);
   ret[len - 1] = in[0];
   return ret;
}
```

or for references:

```
public static <T> T[] queueFirst(T[] in) {
   if (in.length <= 1) return in;
   ArrayList<T> n = new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(in));
   n.add(n.remove(0));
   return n.toArray(in);
}
```